# QGIS: Changing CRS

Tags: qgis

I've got a simple project. A base map and a gpx track. Basemap is from OpenLayers. I want to change the map the CRS to Arizona Central so I can use something convenient for QChainage.

When I change away from the default WGS84, my GPX track disappears.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a side note, http://gis.stackexchange.com/ tends to have a more vibrant community for people asking and answering "how to use" GIS questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably what you want to do is **right click on the layer and "save as" a new layer, and then choose the target CRS.** The newly saved layer will have the new CRS and it's coordinates will be translated to the new CRS.

I believe everyone has gotten hung up on this at one point or another.

See here for some details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/how-can-i-change-the-projection-of-shapefile-in-qgis

Essentially, if you change the crs of a layer in QGIS layer properties, it will *not* change the coordinates for the points, but it will just interpret them in that new CRS. Think of it like this:

```
Bob: That tree is 12.3 miles south of here.
You: "Miles" are you serious? I'm from Denmark and would prefer if you could tell me in kilometers.
Bob: Oh sure. No problem. That tree is 12.3 kilometers south of here.
```

Obviously that is not what you wanted.

In actuality, projections involve a lot more than just converting from (e.g.) miles to kilometers, but I think the analogy is decent.

So why is Lazy Bob so lazy? I don't know, but I could guess: QGIS tries to be really clear about when it's editing your data vs just looking at things. If you were to "change the projection" of a file, it would actually correspondingly change all the points in your file to that new projection. This could take a while, and can potentially be destructive e.g. you could lose a little accuracy if you are switching back and forth between projections all the time.

Comment: Thank you ++++. Now I can use QChainage to add mile (well 5280 ft) markers. Thank you Michael. Just recognized your photo. Somehow I'd missed that this got answered and I got sidetracked on other stuff. Greg from MaptimeLA.